# My case statement is not working, but the logic looks correct to me

Tags: ruby

This program prints the first statement, and exits after I enter a number e.g. "5", without printing anything else. From the logic I put in the `case` statement, I would expect it to output "You're not an adult :(" for 5. Other values lower than 120 do not work as expected either.

What is wrong?

```
print "Enter you age "
age = gets.chomp

if age.to_i<120
  case age.to_i
  when age.to_i<18
    puts "You're not an adult :("
    puts "Sorry"

  when age.to_i>18
    puts "You are now an adult!"
    puts "phew"
  end
end
```

Comment: Since you're using `age.to_i` repeatedly, what you really want is to do `age = gets.chomp.to_i` to convert once and then use that. Also what happens when someone puts in 18? That's not going to match either case. You're also preventing anyone younger than 120 from seeing your message.

Comment: Whta is wrong? You state it.

Comment: You are asking whether a boolean matches a number. Obviously, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Notice I've dropped the `age.to_i` from the `case` statement:

```
print "Enter you age "
age = gets.chomp

if age.to_i<120
    case
        when age.to_i<18
            puts "You're not an adult :("
            puts "Sorry"

        when age.to_i>18
            puts "You are now an adult!"
            puts "phew"
        end
    end
```

**EDIT**

A little explanation is in order.

When you write this:

```
case foo
  when "bar"
    ...
```

That essentially means:

```
if "bar" === foo
  ...
```

So your code was sort of like this:

```
if age.to_i<18 === age.to_i
  ...
```

which doesn't make a lot of sense. If you just write `case` with nothing after it, then it works more like a regular `if` statement. E.g.

```
case
  when foo === "bar"
    ...
```

means roughly

```
if foo === "bar"
  ...
```

which is what you want. I hope that helps!

Comment: @KarenB Did you mean `case age.to_i < 18`?

Comment: Yup, I sure did, thanks.   I blame cat on the keyboard.  Will fix.

Comment: (Reposting edited comment) `case age.to_i < 18/when true/when false` would also work and feels a little more natural to me. Also, doesn't miss the case when age.to_i == 18

Comment: To expand on sawa's comment, `case foo; when bar` tests `bar === foo` (and in that specific order). So for instance `Integer === 1` is true whilst `1 === Integer` is false. This is relevant for testing class in e.g. `case foo; when Integer ....`

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks! I've updated my answer to use `===`.

Comment: The `===` is not necessary (although it will work for OP) for the last two examples with the explicit test in the `when` statement. It is not commonly used operator - which is why it trips people up when it turns up implied in things like `case` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up version:

```
print "Enter you age "
age = gets.chomp.to_i

case age
when 0..18
  puts "You're not an adult :("
  puts "Sorry"
when 18..120
  puts "You are now an adult!"
  puts "phew"
else
  puts "I think you're lying!"
end
```

Folding all of this into a single `case` statement and using ranges makes what's happening a lot more clear.

Comment: I believe `chomp` is not required here either.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Technically no, the `to_i` will clear that out anyway.